# DeprecationWarning: Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pygame, python-3.8

Me salta el error de `DeprecationWarning` tengo que convertir a `int` pero ya lo hize igual no me funciona,
me dice lo siguiente:

> ```
> El juego de la Vida.py:48: DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).
> Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.      
>   pygame.draw.polygon(screen,(128,128,128), poly, int(abs(gameState[x, y])))
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "El juego de la Vida.py", line 39, in <module>
>     new_gameState[x, y]=1
> TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
> ```

```
import sys, pygame
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 600, 600

bg = 25, 25, 25

nxC=60

nyC=60

dimCW=(width - 1)/nxC

dimCH=(height - 1)/nyC

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.fill(bg)
gameState=np.zeros((nxC, nyC))

gameState[21,21]=1
gameState[22,22]=1
gameState[22,23]=1
gameState[21,23]=1
gameState[20,23]=1

while 1:
    new_gameState=np.copy(gameState)
    screen.fill(bg)
    for y in range(0, nyC):
        for x in range(0, nxC):
              n_neigh = gameState[(x-1)%nxC, (y-1)%nyC] +\
                      gameState[(x)%nxC, (y-1)%nyC]+\
                      gameState[(x+1)%nxC, (y-1)%nyC]+\
                      gameState[(x-1)%nxC, (y)%nyC]+\
                      gameState[(x+1)%nxC, (y)%nyC]+\
                      gameState[(x-1)%nxC, (y+1)%nyC]+\
                      gameState[(x)%nxC, (y+1)%nyC]+\
                      gameState[(x+1)%nxC, (y+1)%nyC]
              if gameState[x, y]==0 and n_neigh==3:
                      new_gameState[x, y]=1
              elif gameState[x, y]==1 and (n_neigh<2 or n_neigh>3):
                      new_gameState=0

            poly=[((x)* dimCW, (y) * dimCH),
                ((x+1)* dimCW,        (y) * dimCH),
                ((x+1)*dimCW,         (y+1) * dimCH), 
                ((x)* dimCW,    (y+1) * dimCH)]

            pygame.draw.polygon(screen,(128,128,128), poly, int(abs(gameState[x, y])))
    gameState=new_gameState
    time.sleep(0.1)                                            
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos problemas:

- Un warning (que no error, lo cual no quiere decir que lo ignores). Es un `DeprecationWarning` que quiere decir como el mismo error deja claro que la conversión implícita a integuer de las coordenadas cuando éstas son `floats` se va a eliminar en un futuro y que ocasionará una excepción si no pasamos enteros.

  El problema es que estás apuntando mal, es `poly` la lista de tuplas con los puntos del polígono la que contiene floats como coordenadas y es esto lo que lanza el warning. Trunca o redondea simplemente:

  ```
  poly=[round(x * dimCW), round((y) * dimCH),
        round((x + 1) * dimCW), round((y) * dimCH),
        round((x + 1) * dimCW), round((y+1) * dimCH), 
        round((x * dimCW)), round((y+1) * dimCH)]
  ```
- Además tienes un error (una verdadera excepción que si termina con la ejecución del programa en ese mismo instante) que es lo que viene después del warning y que nada tiene que ver con él:

  > TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

  Se debe a que tienes un error en:

  ```
  elif gameState[x, y]==1 and (n_neigh<2 or n_neigh>3):
      new_gameState=0
  ```

  le estás asignando un entero a la variable `new_gameState`  que es un array antes de eso. Cuando intentas hacer `new_gameState[x, y]=1` en la siguiente iteración tienes el error porque intentas indizar y asignar a un `int`, no a un array. Debe ser:

  ```
  elif gameState[x, y] == 1 and (n_neigh < 2 or n_neigh > 3):
      new_gameState[x, y] = 0
  ```

Answer (score 0):

yo también seguí el tutorial y tuve el mismo error. Lo que me funcionó fue convertir los elementos del "*poly*" en **int**, te muestro el código que usé:

```
poly = [
                (int(x * dimCW), int(y * dimCH)),
                (int((x + 1) * dimCW), int(y * dimCH)),
                (int((x + 1) * dimCW), int((y + 1) * dimCH)),
                (int(x * dimCW), int((y + 1) * dimCH)),
            ]
```

Y después utilicé la siguiente línea, si llamar al gameState:

```
pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (128, 128, 128), poly, 1)
```